# How import npm module 'mapbox-gl' in meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, mapbox-gl

The npm module [mapbox-gl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl) failed at import in Meteor 1.3.

This is how the import looks like:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
```

The error in the browser console:

```
Cannot find module 'gl'
```

- Is it a problem of Meteor's packager?
- Can this package only be used through Browserify?

Comment: 'meteor-node-stubs' and 'mapbox-gl' are installed and saved to package.json. So that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in solving this baby. Copied from the mapbox-gl repo...

*Alternatively, you can npm install mapbox-gl and use it as a bundled dependency with browserify.*

It seems like it may depend on browserify? Why mapbox!! If I come up with a solution will post here.. Until then may God have mercy on our souls c:

update:: it is on!
[mapbox error of d00m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPfyT.png)

update2:: the require statements inside mapboxgl.js are causing the errors.. My previous console error stemmed from not having the npm 'gl' package loaded before mapbox.

Any ideas how to debrowserify an npm package??

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and there is no solution at the moment. You can still include `mapbox-gl` with a `script` tag:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.22.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
```